# Passing instance variables into API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, instance-variables

I'm trying to pass in some instance variables to call an API with that specific object's attributes. A user fills in their car details (make, model, and year) which creates an offer object. That is supposed to be passed into Edmund's API to retrieve the info for that car. The code works fine if I set it with a specific make/model/year but I can't make it return info for a created offer object.

Here's my controller:

```
def show
@offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
@wanted_ad = WantedAd.find(params[:wanted_ad_id])
@make = @offer.ownermake
@model = @offer.ownermodel
@year = @offer.owneryear

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @offer }
end
end
```

And here's my model:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :wanted_ad_id, :estvalue, :image1, :offerprice, :ownercartype, :ownerdesc, :ownermake, :ownermileage, :ownermodel, :owneryear
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :wanted_ad
    has_one :car

    def self.carsearch
        @car = []


        carinfo = HTTParty.get("http://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/vehicle/#{make}/#{model}/#{year}?api_key=qd4n48eua7r2e59hbdte5xd6&fmt=json")
        carinfo["modelYearHolder"].each do |p|
            c = Car.new
            c.make = p["makeName"]


            return carinfo
    end 
    end
end
```

My car model is simply:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base   
  attr_accessible :make, :model, :year 

  belongs_to :offer  
end
```

And I'm trying to call it from a view file with `<%= Offer.carsearch %>`. I'm probably all sorts of messed up but this is my first time working with an API and I'm very lost.

Comment: My first question would be, why is `carsearch` a class method on the Offer class instead of an instance method? I.e., why `def self.carsearch` instead of `def carsearch` ?

Comment: I've tried both and neither work :\ It was a futile attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got several logical errors in your `carsearch` method:
You're fetching a carinfo, iterate through an array, instantiate a new car but nothing happens with the `c` object and at the end of the first iteration you exit the whole function returning the retrieved `carinfo`...

Is this probably what you've meant?

```
def carsearch
    @cars = []

    # where do `make`, `model` and `year` come from here?
    # probably method parameters!?
    carinfo = HTTParty.get("http://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/vehicle/#{make}/#{model}/#{year}?api_key=qd4n48eua7r2e59hbdte5xd6&fmt=json")
    carinfo["modelYearHolder"].each do |p|
        c = Car.new
        c.make = p["makeName"]
        # initialize other attributes (year, model)?
        @cars << c
    end


    return @cars
end
```

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the method and putting in the carinfo stuff into the controller. It worked that way. Thanks!